# How does looks 'main event loop' in legacy java apps [JCIP 9.1]

Tags: java, user-interface, concurrency, event-loop

I am reading java concuremcy in practice. Now I achieve 9.1 chapter. But I did not develop GUI applications on java.

Quote from book:

> Why are GUIs Single-threaded?
>
> In the old days, GUI applications were single-threaded and GUI events
>   were processed from a "main event loop". Modern GUI frameworks use a
>   model that is only slightly different: they create a dedicated event
>   dispatch thread (EDT) for handling GUI events.

I was not developer in old days thus I don't understand what does mean 'main event loop' in GUI applications. Also google doesn't respond me clear explanation.

Can you show example of this legacy technique? Is there queue for producing and consuming tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in both cases there is a queue where tasks are waiting to be processed, and a thread which executes that tasks one by one.

Main event loop means a dedicated thread which, in a loop, processes all tasks of the application, both related to UI and to all other aspects of the application like I/O and numerical calculations.
This programming model is convenient because being single threaded, it does not require thread synchronization. Anyway, at old days computers had single CPU and multithreading would not give much effect.

Nowadays, an event dispatch thread (EDT) processes only UI requests, allowing I/O and numerical computations run in parallel. Generally, this requires thread synchronization, but communication with EDT remains simple:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    //Code to change Swing data.
  }
});
```

You still can use EDT for all tasks of the application, not only UI, in case your application is light-weight and overloading the EDT would not make UI slow.

Comment: **invokeLater** invokes in parallel with EDT ?

Comment: Yes, invokeLater (task) can be called from any thread. This method simply posts the task to the EDT event queue. EDT takes task from that queue one by one and calls to task.run().

Comment: @gstackoverflow `invokeLater` is used to make things run *on* the EDT - e.g. all interaction with the UI that has to happen from the EDT. You can call `invokeLater` from a thread running in parallel with the EDT to delegate some work back to it.

Comment: @piet.t Why don't write code seqentually at this case?

Comment: @gstackoverflow The use of `invokeLater` is only when you already have code running in parallel to the EDT. You should try to offload most of your heavy work from the EDT to keep your UI responsive even while doing other things like reading a file or doing calculations. But to get your results back to the UI you have to somehow pass them back to the EDT.